# Is this the correct situation to use a service?

Tags: java, android, service

I'm building a fairly simple data tracking app. Using a runnable, every 5 seconds my app checks how much data the user has consumed and updates the UI.

The app works well, and the runnable keeps going even when the app is not in the foreground, but when the app is closed, it stops.

I've never used a service before, and after reading some documentation, I'm still unsure if that's what I need. I need to be able to update the UI, and depending on the data amount, start an asynctask to update a server.

Right now this part is happening from the runnable, but from what I've read about services, it seems like interacting with the UI is difficult.

I was originally hoping that I could somehow just prevent the app from ever being killed. It's going to be used on a private system, so there's no concern of the user 'getting annoyed' that the app can't be closed, but I can't figure out how to pull it off.

Thanks in advance for any information!

Note: I didn't post any code because I didn't think it was relevant here, but I'd be happy to upon request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the correct situation to use a service?

Yes.

> from what I've read about services, it seems like interacting with the UI is difficult.

It's not that hard. The easiest solution would be to use an `EventBus`.

Another solution without a library: The `Activity` binds to the `Service` in `onCreate`. The `Service` returns a `Binder`. The `Activity` passes a `Listener` to that `Binder`. The `Service` calls the `listener` as soon as the UI needs to be updated.